# How can I find out the detailed API of messages?

Tags: ros, rosdoc, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I find out the detailed API of messages?

Point, I can only find the definition here http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html . However, there are many methods such as push_back and so on which are not mention in ros-wiki or ros-api. I think ros must have been befined some iterators and containers. So where are the document of API or source code?

Any suggestion would be appreciate.
Best regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10926/how-can-i-find-out-the-detailed-api-of-messages?/) by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Message generation uses standard C++/Boost data types and containers when creating messages for C++. Variable size arrays are represented by std::vector, fixed size arrays are represented by boost:array. For more information on how to use these, please have a look at your favorite C++ API reference and the boost documentation.

You can find a complete list of data type mappings used in message generation [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on 2011-08-17**:
you provide a very important document. That have been solved my question. Thanks.